A recommended way to use a command-line utility that isn't added to PATH
If I have a command-line utility foo installed by some program, and it is not added to $PATH, and I want to have an easy way to use it, it seems there are three options:

create a symbolic link, usually in /usr/local/bin or maybe $HOME/bin:
ln -s /path/to/foo /usr/local/bin/foo


instead of creating a symbolic link, create an executable:
echo 'path/to/foo' > /usr/local/bin/foo
chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/foo


or edit .zshrc and set an alias:
alias foo='/path/to/foo'



My questions:

Is it correct?
And which of these options is the "best" (OK, I do realize it is a naive way to ask...) or at least preferred more often?


See also the hash built-in (in any POSIX like shell, not just zsh)

I don't know about MacOS, but on Linux these days there is also the ~/.local/bin folder that is often used for this. I have a config file referenced by my .bashrc that lists several paths to add to the PATH. That way I can easily see what I added and remove it.

One obvious solution is to add the directory containing the program to your PATH setting. This is commonly practiced on Windows, but not on Unix. There are several reasons why this isn't a good idea:

Often the directory containing the executable you want also contains non-executable files, executables you don't care about, or subdirectories. Those can clutter completion. (This is less of a problem on Windows where most people don't use the command line, so PATH is mostly for the sake of program-to-program calls.)
You need to find a way to keep track of which directories are in the PATH, and in particular to remove obsolete entries after uninstalling a program. (Windows partially solves this by letting the program's installer take care of the PATH setting. But many programs don't come with a working uninstaller.)
A newly installed program won't be accessible from running shells and other programs until you restart the calling programs. (Windows partially solves this by having a “system PATH” and arranging to run most programs via a shell that obeys this “system PATH”. This excludes running things from a terminal window.)
This doesn't handle things other than executables, such as man pages. (Windows partially solves this by making the program's installer register its help pages. But that assumes the program comes with an installer.)


Creating a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin (for programs installed system-wide) or ~/bin (for programs installed on your account — you can pick a different location if you like) (suggestion 1 in the question) is a good solution. It makes newly installed programs immediately available to all potential callers. Installation just requires creating one symbolic link. Uninstallation just requires removing a symbolic link. If you forget to uninstall the symbolic link, you can easily clean up: just remove all dangling symlinks.
One difficulty with this approach is that it's tedious to remember to create the link. Fortunately, there are tools for that: Stow or one of its alternatives such as XStow. See Keeping track of programs.
Stow and XStow also take care of making associates resources available, for example man pages. After uninstalling a program, they can remove dangling symbolic links.
There are a few programs that don't work properly when you invoke them through a symbolic link, because they expect to find other files in the same directory (or a nearby directory, e.g. when you run /path/to/bin/foo, it looks for /path/to/lib/foolib). Most programs that do that look at the target of the link, but now and then you'll encounter one that looks at the link itself. With such a program, use the shell script wrapper method below.

A shell script wrapper (suggestion 2 in the question) works, but is not convenient. You have to write that wrapper for each program. You have to remember to remove it on uninstallation. It doesn't take care of associated resources such as man pages. So it's more of a fallback method when the symlink approach isn't good enough.
An advantage of the shell script wrapper approach is that it gives you control over the exact path through which you invoke the executable, in case the program cares about it. This also lets you set environment variables, for programs that need special settings in their environment that you don't want to carry around everwhere. It also gives you an opportunity to clean up after the program exist, if the program leaves garbage around (e.g. programs that don't clean up their temporary files).
Here's a minimal shell script wrapper that takes care to do things cleanly. In particular, it passes all command line arguments through correctly. It also takes care not to leave the shell wrapper process around, which occasionally matters if you're doing some kind of process monitoring.
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/my/weird/executable "$@"


A shell alias works only when you call the program directly from an interactive shell. It doesn't work from other programs, or from already running shell instances, or from scheduled tasks, or via utilities such as find -exec or xargs, etc. I can't think of a good reason to use this method.

Re 1) Most shells already ignore directories and non-executable files for the purpose of tab completion from PATH. Bash and PowerShell certainly do. Re 3) I don't think I've seen that kind of special "system PATH" treatment – instead, Windows graphical shell can be signaled to reload its entire environment from registry without needing to restart it, which installers generally do. Re 4) For manpages in particular, the default MANPATH on Linux is derived from PATH (by applying ../man/ to each path), so setting PATH does handle manuals as well.

Note that an alias does get expanded within a shell script.  So if you have callfoo.sh with an alias to foo, then that will work within a shell session.  However, one disadvantage of an alias is that they don't like being redefined.  alias foo=/path/foo will block a latter foo() { /path/foo} function.

@JLPeyret: Only if the script is sourced (i.e. run inline within the interactive shell). Scripts run as a separate process (which is the majority of them) don't have any way to automatically inherit aliases defined in the interactive session (and also start with the "alias expansion" shell flag disabled). Might be different for zsh if someone puts aliases in zshenv, I guess.

@grawity In zsh, aliases are enabled by default, so you don't need a specific option like shopt -s expand_aliases in Bash.

I've never had a Mac, but I do this with an alias constantly.  If .zshrc is the Mac equivalent of .bashrc, then just add:
if [ -f ~/.zsh_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.zsh_aliases
fi

Then run: touch ~/.zsh_aliases
Now just use any text editor to add all your aliases to that file, and it will load automatically on startup.  You can either reboot or type source ~/.zshrc (or . , like above, is the same as source) to do it without restarting.
Some .zsh_aliases examples directly from my file:
alias pdf2console='bash -c /run/media/jason/HOME/jaypc/Documents/pub/bash/myapps/pdf2console.sh
alias concatvid='/run/media/jason/HOME/jaypc/Documents/pub/bash/myapps/1_ffmpeg/concat_vid.sh'
alias mdedit='firefox /home/jason/Documents/htdocs/md2html/md-it/index.html'

I'm not sure if there is a zsh equivlant to bash -c, but it shouldn't be necessary.  Use it with the full path like conctvid and you can run that script, executable, or anything, from any directory with arguments and all. The alias mdedit opens my browser based markdown editor in firefox.  You can do a lot.
I even have the alias aka, to edit my aliases file with nano, and run source on exit:
alias aka='nano ~/.zsh_aliases && source ~/.zshrc'

